# Autoplaying an embedded video in fullscreen from commandline (Chrome or Firefox)?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, command-line, fullscreen, autoplay

Is there a way to launch either Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox from the commandline so that it automatically plays the video on the specified URL (motogp.com in this case) in fullscreen mode?
Installing additional extensions would not be a problem.

Comment: I know about the --kiosk parameter in Chrome but that does not put the video player in fullscreen, only the webpage.